# Why can't app start from recents if paused too long

Tags: android

I've noticed an issue when I pause my app, say by pressing home, and then bring up the list of recent apps (via the square button) to resume it.

If I resume it shortly after pausing it, it works fine.  But if I leave it paused for too long, i.e. a few hours or overnight, then when I touch its window to resume it, it just posts a "failed to start..." toast and removes the app from the list.

I've searched around, but haven't found any info about what would cause this or how to start debugging it.

Answer (score 0):

My theory would be that is has to do with the activity lifecycle. You can find it here:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html

When an app is paused, the onPause() function is called, and if the app is paused, and the system needs memory for another app that is running in the foreground, it will stop, or destroy the activity. When you go back into the app, it calls the onCreate() and onStart() functions

I don't know how your app is structured, but my guess is that when the activity is stopped, it is leaving behind some kind of code that needs to reference something that is no longer there, or destroying the referenced thing itself. Then, when onStart() is called, it checks for that thing that is no longer there and crashes.

The best way to fix this is to make sure that each step of the life cycle isn't referencing anything that could possibly be non existent at the time it is called.

Comment: I'll take a look, so far I haven't seen any evidence that it is a crash, although it is tricky to reproduce, so I haven't reproduced it when I had a dev environment handy to look for a stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

When the user leaves a task by pressing the Home button, the current activity is stopped and its task goes into the background. The system retains the state of every activity in the task. If the user later resumes the task by selecting the launcher icon that began the task, the task comes to the foreground and resumes the activity at the top of the stack.

If the user leaves a task for a long time, the system clears the task of all activities except the root activity. When the user returns to the task again, only the root activity is restored. The system behaves this way, because, after an extended amount of time, users likely have abandoned what they were doing before and are returning to the task to begin something new.

You might look up into the Android documentation regarding [Tasks and Back Stack](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) and upon some information about [Pausing and Resuming](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html) an activity. :)

Comment: It looks like that clearing happens if the app is relaunched from the home screen.  I'm only seeing this problem if I try to launch the app from the recent apps list, not from the home screen.

Answer (score 0):

You issue probably related to memory management on android. It looks like android kills you app to release memory so that it can be used by another app. I have an app with very complex layout (The app loads too many images). After some times, when I run the app from recent app list, it always run the app from start. Not from the last state where I left the app. Anywa, nothing to worry about. This is normal behaviour.

Comment: It would be OK if it restarted from the initial state; the issue I'm seeing is that it sometimes it doesn't start from the recents list.

Answer (score 0):

**As of my concern this is your problem-**

- you are starting an activity.
- then you press home button. and the activity goes to background.
- when you start the app after 5 minutes the app starts from the paused activity. but when you start app after 5 hours the app starts from the beginning.

**Solution-**

- This is happening because the activity is being killed in background by the android system.
- the application can be killed by calling the ondestroy() method of the activity.
- and when the app goes to background it is added to the application stack of the android system. when ever android needs more memory for any operation it takes memory from the last application in the application stack. it kills the last application and takes its memory.
- this is the reason your app is being killed after long time. your app is at the last of the stack and android has killed your app to get memory.
- you can find more explanation of the process [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

**How to solve this problem**

- this can be solved by bringing your app to front of the stack periodically.
- you can run a service from your activity in background so that is stays on top side of stack.
- or save the last opened activity in a shared preference and go to this activity when the app starts.

Comment: It's not an issue of starting in the wrong state.  The issue is that the app doesn't start at all.

Comment: The recents list doesn't really show an icon, it shows a preview window.  Clicking on that shows a toast.

Comment: Toast saying what?